# Selecting certain regions in a 3D array (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I made a 3D array in python in which every element represents an uncertainty corresponding to an image voxel. I would like to find regions in this 3D array where the uncertainty (represented by a certain measure) is high. I was thinking about choosing a thresholh for example to look for this regions.

The problem is I don't have much experience in python and I don't really know how to start to look for this regions? Looking for a 2D plane of this 3D array in which the uncertainty is high is not that difficult but now I really want to find then smaller regions in all the 2D planes of the 3D array in which the uncertainty is high.